# How to conditionally add arguments of optional parameters in python?

Tags: python

If I have a function defined with default values, and I want to use them conditionally
Eg. In the function below -

```
def foo(arg1='some_default_string1', arg2='some_default_string1'):
    print(arg1,arg2)
```

If I had to call the function with a1_string/a2_string either having values or not.

```
if a1_string and not a2_string:
    foo(a1_string)
elif not a1_string and a2_string
    foo(a2_string)
elif a1_string and a2_string:
    foo(a1_string, a2_string)
else:
    foo()
```

could this be done in a single line such as

```
foo(a1_string?, a2_string?)
```

Comment: I am not understanding your question.  Would naming the variables in your function call do it, e.g., `foo(a2_string="XXXXX")` or could you use `**kwargs` to get what you want?

Comment: if you are passing both `arg1` and `arg2` anyway, then you don't need the default value because they are used when there are fewer arguments than defined. Just do something like `print(arg1 or "default1", arg2 or "default2")`

Comment: Please could you edit the question to show different scenarios (e.g. combinations of value for `a1_string` and `a2_string`) and the output you want in each case?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `or` operator:

```
def foo(arg1='some_default_string1', arg2='some_default_string2'):
    arg1 = arg1 or 'some_default_string1'
    arg2 = arg2 or 'some_default_string2'
    print(arg1, arg2)
```

This would work for all cases.

Comment: Let's say a2_string is not defined. 
How do I go about printing just foo(a1_string, a2_string)
without it giving an error that a2_string is undefined.